# How do i blue border after highlight elements in live preview?

Tags: html, css, adobe-brackets

when i click on the div or element in brackets the live preview in chrome does flash blue and then fade away , but it does not leave a **thin blue border** around the element like what i have seen in other peoples videos, Please HELP!

Comment: Are you sure the other people's videos don't have thin blue borders in the CSS?

Comment: show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking about the indicator that some browsers place around in-focus elements (which don't otherwise have custom `:focus` css).

Different browsers handle this differently.  If you want a specific focus indicator you need to either create it yourself in CSS, or use whichever browser the people in your videos are using.